# cython doesn't support sorted with key?

Tags: python, cython

```
def test():
    return sorted([(a,b) for a in xrange(10) for b in xrange(10)],
       key=lambda (x,y): x + y)
```

The above is valid python code, yet triggers an error in cython. The error message is`Expected ')', found ','`.

What's wrong here?

Python 2.7, Cython 0.19.2

Comment: The key is not the problem, but the lambda - because it works with other keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cython does not support [nested tuple argument unpacking](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/limitations.html#nested-tuple-argument-unpacking).

Your `lambda` uses nested tuple arguments:

```
lambda (x,y): x + y
```

Replace that with:

```
lambda x: x[0] + x[1]
```

or even just:

```
sum
```

and perhaps mix in some `itertools.product()` too here, as in:

```
from itertools import product

def test():
    return sorted(product(xrange(10), repeat=2), key=sum)
```

but then you mostly end up with code mostly served by C routines anyway..

Comment: or, more pythonic, just use `key=sum`

Comment: @wim: Indeed; cython supports that too. :-)